# Dynamic initial Route for React Navigation SwitchNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation-v3 to build a movie-streaming app.

The app has a familiar bottom tab navigation on the landing page (after login), showing three tabs - WATCH NOW, FAVOURITES and SETTINGS.

The landing page ("Watch Now") shows a list of movies to the user.

I have developed a new module, which allows user to view SERIES on the app as well.

Now my app will show MOVIES and SERIES in 2 separate top-tabs (as seen below) in the same bottom Navigation tab "Watch Now".

I want to make this feature dynamic - that is, if I turn off SERIES from the server, my route should change to reflect that only MOVIES exist now as they did originally (without the material top tab).

Here's my routing config -

```
export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        // Loading screen, authenticates user and redirects them where appropriate
        Loading,

        // Tutorial Screens
        Tutorial: TutorialTabs,

        // Authentication Stack, Sign-In/Up and forget password.
        Auth: AuthStack,

        // Main Stack, all other screens
        App: AppStack,
    },

    {
        initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    }
));
```

Here's the *AppStack* used above -

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    // Default Screen, Main bottom-tab-navigator.
    Main : switchStack,
    About,
    WebContent,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName : 'Main',
    defaultNavigationOptions: getStackNavigationOptions,
    mode: 'modal'
  },
);
```

And here's the SwitchNavigator I'm using to switch between only Movies, and Movies + Series -

```
const switchStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  'PageWithMoviesAndSeries' : PageWithMoviesAndSeries,
  'PageWithMoviesOnly' : PageWithMoviesOnly,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName : getInitialRouteName()
  }
);
```

I tried to switch between the two using the function getInitialRouteName() defined below -

```
function getInitialRouteName() {
  if(window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled === true)
    return 'PageWithMoviesAndSeries';
  return 'PageWithMoviesOnly';
}
```

I'm setting this *window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled* variable in my root *App.js*, after emulating a network operation using setTimeOut.

```
    window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled = false;

    setTimeout(() => {

      window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled = true;

}, 2000);
```

And finally, this is how my appContainer is being used in App.js (root) -

```
render() {
    const { activityIndicatorVisible, activityIndicatorMessage } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={this.onLayout}>
        <AppContainer
          ref={nav => {this.navigator = nav;}}
          onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationStateChange}
        />
        {this.renderGeolocationRequestRationale()}
        <ActivityIndicator
          visible={activityIndicatorVisible}
          message={activityIndicatorMessage}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But the **problem** is, that even after setting the variable *window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled*, my app is not routing to the appropriate screen, because for some reason, getInitialRouteName() is only invoked once (before I set the *window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled* variable value).

I'm totally stumped by this simple issue.

I looked up on StackOverflow, Github, but none of the solutions that I have encountered have worked or are relevant for this version (v3) of react-navigation library.

Please help me figure out how to dynamically assign a routeName to the app based on server configuration.
Thanks.

**EDIT : ** Had a typo in window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled variable. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You look using different key at `getInitialRouteName` function.

```
isStreamingSeriesEnabled
isStreamingEnabled
```

```js
function getInitialRouteName() {
  if(window.isStreamingSeriesEnabled === true)
    return 'PageWithMoviesAndSeries';
  return 'PageWithMoviesOnly';
}
```

```js
window.isStreamingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my end. Have edited the question. Thanks for pointing out.